# Why is my TODAY function in IF formula returning a value other than 0?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to write the If statement below in a Google Sheet:

If today's date is greater than the payment deadline, then return the overdue payment amount. Otherwise, return 0.

I did this:

```
=if(F11<"=TODAY()",C11,0) + if(F12<"=TODAY()",C12,0) + if(F13<"=TODAY()",C13,0) + if(F14<"=TODAY()",C14,0) + if(F15<"=TODAY()",C15,0) + if(F16<"=TODAY()",C16,0) + if(F17<"=TODAY()",C17,0)
```

- The values in column F are dates written the date format month/day/year. **All of the dates in column F are greater than today's date.**
- The values in column C are dollar amounts with decimals.

#### First Attempt:

```
=if(F11<"=TODAY()",C11,0) + if(F12<"=TODAY()",C12,0) + if(F13<"=TODAY()",C13,0) + if(F14<"=TODAY()",C14,0) + if(F15<"=TODAY()",C15,0) + if(F16<"=TODAY()",C16,0) + if(F17<"=TODAY()",C17,0)
```

#### Second Attempt:

```
=if(F11<"TODAY()",C11,0) + if(F12<"TODAY()",C12,0) + if(F13<"TODAY()",C13,0) + if(F14<"TODAY()",C14,0) + if(F15<"TODAY()",C15,0) + if(F16<"TODAY()",C16,0) + if(F17<"TODAY()",C17,0)
```

#### Third Attempt:

```
=if(DATEVALUE(F11)<"TODAY()",C11,0) + if(DATEVALUE(F12)<"TODAY()",C12,0) + if(DATEVALUE(F13)<"TODAY()",C13,0) + if(DATEVALUE(F14)<"TODAY()",C14,0) + if(DATEVALUE(F15)<"TODAY()",C15,0) + if(DATEVALUE(F16)<"TODAY()",C16,0) + if(DATEVALUE(F16)<"TODAY()",C17,0)
```

I expect to get 0 overdue payments as all the payment deadlines are greater than today's day. Could you please help me?

Comment: There shouldn't be any quote marks anywhere in the formula - you are comparing against the literal text `=TODAY()` or `TODAY()`, not anything related to today's date.

Answer (score 1):

your formula should be:

```
=IF(F11<TODAY(), C11, 0) + 
 IF(F12<TODAY(), C12, 0) + 
 IF(F13<TODAY(), C13, 0) + 
 IF(F14<TODAY(), C14, 0) + 
 IF(F15<TODAY(), C15, 0) + 
 IF(F16<TODAY(), C16, 0) + 
 IF(F17<TODAY(), C17, 0)
```

next level formula would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(F11:F17<TODAY(), C11:C17, 0)))
```

or shorter:

```
=SUMIF(F11:F17, "<"&TODAY(), C11:C17)
```